# What is the difference between a Layout, Sublayout, and Rendering?

Tags: presentation, documentation

In Sitecore, under `/sitecore/layouts`, I see the following:

- Layouts
- Sublayouts
- Renderings

**What are these, and what makes them different?**  Are there any other types of layouts?

Comment: Here is the great [link](https://www.jondjones.com/learn-sitecore-cms/sitecore-developers-guide/sitecore-core-concept/sitecore-data-template-content-layouts-and-components), this might help any one like me.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

### Layouts

- Provide the outermost HTML structure of a page.
- There is **one** layout (per device) per page.
- Apply to WebForms (.aspx) **and** MVC (.cshtml)
- Comprise of Layout definition item and aspx page (WebForms) or cshtml file (MVC)

### Sublayouts

- Provide inner HTML structure to a component or structuring element of a page.
- Apply only to WebForms
- Comprise of a definition item + .ascx control.
- Can contain nested Sublayouts within their placeholders

### Renderings

- Provide inner HTML structure to a component or structuring element of a page.
- Can be used with WebForms (if using XSLT) OR MVC
- Sitecore MVC uses the following rendering sub-types:

  - Controller rendering: rendering definition item references a controller and action name
  - View rendering: rendering definition item references a view (cshtml file) and optionally a viewmodel (which in turn references a model type in code)
  - Item rendering: rendering definition item does not reference a controller or a view, instead it serves as a kind of 'placeholder'. The datasource item should have a rendering type associated with it via the __renderers field. Setting the datasource of an item rendering causes Sitecore to look at the datasource item itself to decide which rendering to use.
- Comprise of a definition item + .xslt or .cshtml view
- Can contain nested renderings (or sublayouts [1]) within their placeholders

[1] can only contain nested sublayout if xslt rendering within a WebForms solution

More information on MVC-specific aspects can be found here: http://www.matthewdresser.com/sitecore/sitecore-mvc-presentation-concepts